# Como usar um NSString para criar um NSPredicate?

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nspredicate

Estou criando uma busca personalizada, porém estou criando a strings do predicate como um NSString. Porém estou recebendo um erro.

Código utilizado:

```
NSMutableString* escolhasSIM = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];

// Posição 0
    if ([[arrayEscolhas objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:@"sim"]) {

         [escolhasSIM appendFormat:@"pizza==sim AND "];
    }


    // Posição 1
    if ([[arrayEscolhas objectAtIndex:1] isEqualToString:@"sim"]) {

        [escolhasSIM appendFormat:@"refrigerante==sim AND "];
    }

// Remove os 5 últimos caracteres para limpar a string
NSString *escolhasSimLimpo = [escolhasSIM substringToIndex:[escolhasSIM length]-5];

// ficando @"pizza==sim AND refrigerante==sim"

// Criando NSPredicate

NSPredicate* argumentosBusca = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: escolhasSimLimpo];
```

Porém estou recebendo o seguinte erro:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to generate SQL for
>   predicate (pizza == sim) (problem on RHS)'

Comment: `sim` é uma string, então precisa estar dentro de apóstrofos, como `"refrigerante == 'sim'"`. Uma dica, utilize *array* (depois faça *join*) ao invés de `NSMutableString` e depois ter que remover caracteres, seu código fica mais limpo.

Comment: Valeu @PauloRodrigues vou revisar o código sim, é pq so estou elaborando uma solução rápida, depois vou refinar isso.

Comment: Eu recomendaria utilizar `NSCompoundPredicate` no lugar da `NSMutableString`. Em minha opinião deixaria o código mais limpo e com mais significado da sua intenção.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cometi o erro de incluir a PROPRIEDADE junto a SIM.

Na verdade deve-se colocar o argumento que será comparado entre aspas, ficando o código assim:

```
NSMutableString* escolhasSIM = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];

// Posição 0
    if ([[arrayEscolhas objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:@"sim"]) {

          // Modo ERRADO
          //[escolhasSIM appendFormat:@"pizza==sim AND "];

            // Modo CORRETO
            [escolhasSIM appendFormat:@"pizza==\"sim\" AND "];
    }


    // Posição 1
    if ([[arrayEscolhas objectAtIndex:1] isEqualToString:@"sim"]) {

        // Modo ERRADO
        //[escolhasSIM appendFormat:@"refrigerante==sim AND "];

        // Modo CORRETO
          [escolhasSIM appendFormat:@"refrigerante==\"sim\" AND "];
    }

// Remove os 5 últimos caracteres para limpar a string
NSString *escolhasSimLimpo = [escolhasSIM substringToIndex:[escolhasSIM length]-5];

// ficando @"pizza==sim AND refrigerante==sim"

// Criando NSPredicate

NSPredicate* argumentosBusca = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: escolhasSimLimpo];
```